# Invalid value posted for <variation> WooCommerce after altering variable.php

Tags: templates, variables, woocommerce

I have a variable product in a WooCommerce webshop. I am altering `/single-product/add-to-card/variable.php` for styling reasons. Currently it's inside a table structure that comes out of the box with WooCommerce

I am trying to put my variations inside Bootstrap collapse divs to make it seem a bit neater, thus getting rid of the table. I come a far way. My dropdown for the variation is visible and the collapsable divs work. The correct options for the variations are also shown.

However, not all variations work when I add them to my cart, giving me the message: `Invalid value posted for <variation name>`, in this case that is `Loop`.

I looked through the `add-to-cart-variation.js` file based on a topic I've read about a similar issue, with no luck.

My guess is that because of changes within the DOM, the JavaScript file can not find the correct element anymore. My current `variable.php` looks like this (note: I am using Blade as templating engine):

```
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.5
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

$attribute_keys  = array_keys( $attributes );
$variations_json = wp_json_encode( $available_variations );
$variations_attr = function_exists( 'wc_esc_json' ) ? wc_esc_json( $variations_json ) : _wp_specialchars( $variations_json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo $variations_attr; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', __( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <div id="accordion">
                    @foreach ($attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) @php $index = 1; @endphp

                        <button class="btn btn-link accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
                            <div class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label></div><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body value">
                                <div class="value">
                                    <?php
                                        wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
                                            array(
                                                'options'   => $options,
                                                'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                                'product'   => $product,
                                            )
                                        );
                                        echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    @php $index++ @endphp @endforeach

                    <button class="btn btn-link accordion-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#productDescription" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
                        Description<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div id="productDescription" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {{ $product->get_description() }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <?php
                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_single_variation. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                 *
                 * @since 2.4.0
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' );
```

Please let me know if there's any additional information required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same error in my WC setup, using default template files. For me, it seems to be a bug in WC and it happens when you change the Attributes (Product Data > Attributes) after they've been assigned. Somewhere WC looses the connection to the defined Variations (Product Data > Variations). If I reassign all of them, or regenerate the Variations from scratch, everything works again. It's hard to reproduce, but somehow my client always manages to break it :)

So before you search in code, be sure your problem is not the same as mine.

Edit: I've found that it's related to my custom select input. I use selectric.js to style my select dropdown with custom colors per variation.
When I remove selectric.js, the error doesn't show.
But, regenerating the Variations DOES still help. Will try to figure out why this is happening and if it can be helpful to you.

Update: There was a mysterious conflict between selectric.js and WC's javascript. I've replaced selectric.js with Select2, which WC itself also uses. When I got that error, it was related to incorrect $_SESSION data that the form sends. I think your issue is different then mine, but there's something strange going on. Sorry I couldn't help you further, good luck.